# List of permissions in flutter to take screenshot from background

Tags: flutter, dart, screenshot, screen-scraping, background-process

How could take a screenshot in the background in the flutter, what permission needs to take from the user?
While app running in the background it takes a screenshot of the foreground app or screen with time?

Answer (score -1):

check out the library on pub dev - https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot#-installing-tab-

Comment: did you use this package?